# Equality in product topology spaces.

Tags: general-topology

I have the following problem:

> Given $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$ topological spaces then 
>   $$\partial (A\times B)=(\partial A \times \bar B) \cup (\bar A \times  \partial B) $$

I  have no clear how to begin with the part $(\rightarrow)$. How can I get an "or"?

Comment: think about an example, such as $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Comment: A picture is clear to me, but I don't know how to prove this formally. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it mean for $(x,y)$ to be in the boundary of $A\times B$ ? Can you show that either

- for every open $x\in U\subseteq X$ and $y\in V\subseteq Y$

  1. there are $a\in A\cap U$ and a $b\in B\cap V$, and
  2. there is a $u\in U\setminus A$

or

- for every open $x\in U\subseteq X$ and $y\in V\subseteq Y$

  1. there are $a\in A\cap U$ and a $b\in B\cap V$, and
  2. there is a $v\in V\setminus B$

Either case corresponds to one of the sets in the union on the right side of the equation to be shown.